# What do __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS and __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS mean?

Tags: c++, stl, macros

I see this in the standard C++ libraries for my system, as well as some of the headers in a library I'm using.

What are the semantics of these two definitions?  Is there a good reference for #defines like this other than the source itself?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` and `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` are a workaround to allow C++ programs to use `stdint.h` macros specified in the C99 standard that aren't in the C++ standard. The macros, such as `UINT8_MAX`, `INT64_MIN`, and `INT32_C()` may be defined already in C++ applications in other ways. To allow the user to decide if they want the macros defined as C99 does, many implementations require that `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` and `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` be defined before `stdint.h` is included.

This isn't part of the C++ standard, but it has been adopted by more than one implementation.

Comment: That strikes me as a dangerous naming precedent.  It complicates the life of the standardizers - do they have to pay attention to what implementations have done with their namespace.

Comment: does not apply to C11 anymore and thus C++11.

Answer (score 8):

The above issue has vanished. C99 is an old standard, so this has been explicitly overruled in the C++11 standard, and as a consequence C11 has removed this rule.

More details there:

- https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15366

Answer (score 4):

In `stdint.h` under C++, they control whether to define macros like `INT32_MAX` or `INT32_C(v)`. See your platform's `stdint.h` for additional information.

Answer (score -6):

The macros are not part of the C++ standard and are probably used for internal purposes in your C++ implementation. If you want to know more about them, you should ask a question with atag that indicates what that implementation is.