# Which C++ standard header defines SIZE_MAX?

Tags: c++, header, size-t, stdint

I'm working on an existing C++ codebase that happens to use `SIZE_MAX` in a couple of places. I did some refactoring and now `SIZE_MAX` is not defined in one of the modules. This problem appeared when [Travis-CI](http://travis-ci.org) attempted to build the project on Linux. It worked fine before I refactored stuff, but tracing which exact header files were included is difficult.

In an attempt to replicate the problem locally, I installed an Ubuntu VM with the default gcc and was able to reproduce it. Here's the relevant source:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    size_t a = SIZE_MAX;
}
```

The command line is simply:

```
g++ a.cpp
```

The error is:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:5:16: error: ‘SIZE_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
```

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux quartz 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

I have tried including `cstdint`, `stdint.h`, `limits.h`, `inttypes.h`, `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and probably some others, and I can't figure out which specific header file I need for `SIZE_MAX`.

It is important to note that the program I'm working on compiled fine, with `SIZE_MAX` used in various places, before I made some changes. The changes I made caused it to become undefined in *one* `.cpp` source file where it was used (the others continue to be fine). So there exists *some* header file on my system where it is correctly defined.

Comment: Have you tried `cstdint` ... section *[cstdint.syn]* says it should be there but it should also be in `stdint.h`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I have, and the compiler warns me that including that header requires the `-std=c++0x` switch, but this isn't a C++11 program and I don't want to change that. It still fails to find `SIZE_MAX` when including `cstdint` anyway.

Comment: Take a look on this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/snap-discuss/giu_IMZndxI/CYP98BGvf7QJ

Comment: @iammilind: I have read that question. It's not a duplicate. That question is understanding what `SIZE_MAX` means, while my question relates to which header file I need to include to get it.

Comment: @Santhucool: That's interesting, but seems specific to a software package called SNAP that I'm not familiar with and it's unclear how I could fix my program.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's likely that some header defined `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` and `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` before `stdint.h` was included.

Compiling on Linux with `g++ -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS a.cpp` should fix this issue on the older compilers.

[If you'd like to learn more about these macros...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986426/what-do-stdc-limit-macros-and-stdc-constant-macros-mean)

Answer (score 10):

**18.4.1 Header <cstdint> synopsis**

> The header also defines numerous macros of the form:
>
> > INT_[FAST LEAST]{8 16 32 64}_MIN
> >
> > [U]INT_[FAST LEAST]{8 16 32 64}_MAX
> >
> > INT{MAX PTR}_MIN
> >
> > [U]INT{MAX PTR}_MAX
> >
> > {PTRDIFF SIG_ATOMIC WCHAR WINT}{_MAX _MIN}
> >
> > **SIZE_MAX**

**EDIT**

In the current C++11/14 standard, `SIZE_MAX` is introduced and mentioned only in `<cstdint>`. It is also part of `C99`, of which specification C++11 fully includes via the `<cxxx>` headers. So it seems it was not defined prior to C++11.

Comment: @GregHewgill unfortunately I don't have a copy of the C++98/03 standard. I am not even sure it was defined before. I think it is defined by the C99 standard, and afaik, C++11 fully includes C99 specifications.

Comment: @vsoftco: C++ 2003 did not include `cstdint` and therefore did not include `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @BillLynch yes that's what I was basically saying, that it seems to be newly introduced in C++11 (although it was part of C99 before).

Comment: C++03 did not use C99 as a normative reference.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thanks, I edited the answer, I knew also that C++11 was the first version that fully incorporated C99.

Comment: @vsoftco No, no C++-Standard do fully incorporated C-Standards. For example, C99 have `restrict` which C++ do not have. Also there are many things which are different in C than in C++ (type of a character literal, keyword `const`, ...)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I meant that C++11 falls back fully on C99 in terms of normative references. Surely it doesn't include the C99 standard.

Answer (score 3):

> Which C++ standard header defines SIZE_MAX?

Its supposed to be defined in `<cstdint>`, but its optional.

Here are the results on Fedora 22 with GCC 5.1:

```c++
#include <cstdint>

// use SIZE_MAX
```

Results in:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c filters.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.1.1/cstdint:35:0,
                 from filters.cpp:14:
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires  
compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently
experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
filters.cpp: In constructor ‘Filter::Filter(BufferedTransformation*)’:
filters.cpp:305:36: error: ‘SIZE_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
  : Filter(attachment), m_firstSize(SIZE_MAX), m_blockSize(0), m_lastSize(SIZE_M
                                    ^
```

It was simply easier to do the following, and stop worrying about non-portable optional-ness that still causes problems in 2015.

```c++
#include <limits>

#ifndef SIZE_MAX
# ifdef __SIZE_MAX__
#  define SIZE_MAX __SIZE_MAX__
# else
#  define SIZE_MAX std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
# endif
#endif
```

Trying `__SIZE_MAX__` gets you back to the compile time constant that you probably crave. You can see if its defined in the preprocessor with `cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep __SIZE_MAX__`.

(And how/why `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` is ***not*** a compile time constant is another C++ mystery, but that's a different problem).

Comment: "`numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` is not a compile time constant" - with which standard? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max says it is constexpr since C++11 (thanks for hint to user 1913600 - romain-b).

Comment: The alternative definition is `#define SIZE_MAX (static_cast<size_t>(-1))` rather than using `numeric_limits`.