# Arithmetic operation on int32 and int64 with parentheses

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

given this operation:

```
int64_t a_int64, b_int64 = WHATEVER1;
int32_t c_int32 = WHATEVER2;

a_int64 = b_int64 - (c_int32 * 1000000);
```

Is c_int32 promoted to int64_t before the multiply? I know all integers are promoted to at least 'int' size before any arithmetic operations, and to the size of the larger operand for binary operators if this is of greater rank than an int. But are operations inside parentheses' are handled separately from the (second) operation, the substraction?

Comment: to be sure - just use `1000000ULL` to indicate that both arguments of the multiplication should be promoted to at least 64 bits

Comment: Note: `()` are parentheses. Brackets are `[]`.

Comment: @Lashane: Correct would be using the `INT64_C` macro. And OP uses signed integers, suffix `U` is wrong.

Comment: @Ian: If it overflows, it's undefined behavior. You *can't* test for undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF if we get it overflow, then we already get our answer actually - it is not promoted. No?

Comment: @Olaf yeah, `U` should not be used here. But `LL` should be - as OP wants 64 bit multiplication

Comment: @Ian: If it overflows, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants, including doing the multiplication at 64-bit width *in your tests only*, while failing when you try to use this outside of testing.

Comment: @Lashane: No, as I wrote, he should use the macro, not `LL` suffix.

Comment: @EOF ah, I see. I get it now.

Comment: @Ian, per definition the compiler is allowed to throw a dice how to handle undefined behavior. (Overflows for signed numbers are not specified, only the wrap around for unsigned numbers.)

Comment: @Kay I see. Thanks for clarifying further...

Comment: @Olaf, why do you insist of the macro?

Comment: @Olaf if this macro is defined - great, lets use it, if not - lets use traditional postfixes

Comment: The `(c_int32 * 1000000)` subexpression is evaluated as a 32-bit int, so it will probably overflow.

Comment: @ryyker: No, the macro is standard C, see 7.20.4.1

Comment: @Lashane: It is part of `stdint.h`, thus standard and required. Don't believe every comment.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: "is evaluated as a 32-bit int" only if `int` has exactly 32 used bits. Otherwise it is promoted to whatever type `int32_t` is, or the actual size of `int`, whichever is larger.

Comment: @Olaf I don't believe comments, this macro is defined only if `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` is defined

Comment: @Lashane: Please point me at where the standard mentions that macro. I'm afraid, I cannot find it in the standard. And 7.20.4 does not mention the macro is optional either.

Comment: @Lashane: You are aware C and C++ are different languages, are you?

Comment: @Lashane Where is `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` defined?  I am not familiar with this macro.

Comment: @chux check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986426/what-do-stdc-limit-macros-and-stdc-constant-macros-mean

Comment: @Lashane So it appears `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` is defined neither in C, like this post's tag, nor specified to be in C++, yet it is common in many C++.  It that it?

Comment: @chux afair its non standard extension to use some C macros/definitions in C++, as soon as people quite often use c++ compiler to compile c code (and mostly it works) - you need to define it by yourself

Comment: @Olaf what is your point? I've already told you "if this macro is defined - great, lets use it, if not - lets use traditional postfixes". There are at least 2 situations when this macro is not defined (one is standard, one is non standard).

Comment: @Lashane: Using a C++ compiler to compile C code is a very bad idea. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. And the question is tagged C, so we very well can assume a C compiler is used. I would also not compile C code with a Java compiler or try make it compatible with Pytrhon. For C, the `INTn_C` macros are **always** present if `stdint.h` is present. As OP uses `int64_t` which is also defined in `stdint.h`, this is obviously true.

Comment: @chux: Yes, thanks; remove the last sentence. I think you undersand why I added it (I was not the first to become personal, but should know better) ...

Comment: @Olaf the more I work with different c/c++ compilers and libraries, the less I can assume anything, `int64_t` can be defined anywhere (in real world). So my point is still the same: sure that you can use macro, go ahead and use it, trying to be as portable as possible - use sub-set which is common for all standards. So, phrase `For C, the INTn_C macros are always present` - is *always* false :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But are operations inside parentheses' are handled separately from the (second) operation, the substraction?

Yes; the promotions involved in evaluating `c_int32 * 1000000` do not depend in any way on the context. Any necessary conversions due to that context happen on the result, afterward.

That said, `c_int32 * 1000000` is only well-defined in cases where it doesn't overflow; and in such cases, it doesn't matter whether the 64-bit promotion happens before or after the multiplication. So a compiler could legitimately do it either way (e.g., if it sees some optimization opportunity).

Answer (score 2):

[From another good SO post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default):

C99, §6.4.4.1

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the
>   corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

**Table 6**

```
int
long int
long long int
```

So, the automatic promotion of `c_int32` will depend on the size of the integer literal. In this case, on a 32-bit system, your integer literal will easily fit within an `in32_t` variable.

This is not a good way to do integer arithmetic. Make your code as explicit as possible, and leave nothing to chance.

```
a_int64 = b_int64 - ((int64_t)c_int32 * 1000000LL);
```

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but instead of answering the OP's question, it presupposes the correct answer, in the middle of talking about other stuff. The OP asked a specific, reasonable question; any answer should, if nothing else, answer it.

Comment: @ruakh I maintain that the above answers OP's question. It "depends" on the value of the literal itself. I note that on a 32-bit system, it will fit into a 32-bit `int`. To be more explicit, the literal will evaluate to an `int`, and for most possible values of `c_int32`, overflow will occur. The question is addressed, but perhaps not as explicitly as the audience requires.

Comment: C standard is C11, not C99. An answer should cite from the standard.  The final draft n1570 is available for free. And to provide a 64 bit `int` (or the smallest possible type), the `INT64_C` macro is a better choice.

Comment: @Olaf, Agree widening the multiplication to `int64_t` with `INT64_C` or with `(int64_t)` is sufficient.  Using `LL` works but may push the width unnecessarily, which I think is your point, say on a future system where `long long` is 128 bit.  (I went through  a similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19451101/2410359))

Comment: @chux: Yes, that is the idea. On a defined target and with no portability in mind (e.g. an emedded system), I'm actually fine with the suffixes - mostly because I'm a lazy coder, too:-), but SO answers should look further and use the most correct code.

Comment: @Dogbert: But the OP clearly already understood all of those things. His/her question was specifically about when the promotion to `int64_t` takes place. Your answer is basically nitpicking about the parts that the OP expressed less-precisely than you might have wanted, while taking for granted the parts that the OP actually sought an explanation for.