# How to check if fixed width integers are defined

Tags: c++, c++11, types, stdint, cstdint

In C++, fixed width integers are defined as [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), but I can't seems to find the recommended way to check if they are actually defined.

What would be a portable way to check if fixed width integers are available?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be [feature test macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros), but I suppose you can do `#if defined(INT8_MIN)`

Comment: If the std library does not provide a feature test macro for that, then you might check if the toolchain you use provides one for it or allows you to define an own test. CMake, for example, allows you to test for certain language features by compiling a defined `cpp` file and depending on if the compilation fails or not a macro that you can define is set.

Comment: If you prefer autoconf to cmake, it has tests predefined for them. `AC_TYPE_INT8_T` etc.

Comment: If anyone has any tag score in [tag:stdint], IMO [tag:cstdint] should be nominated as a synonym (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdint/synonyms).  I don't think we need separate C and C++ tags for this obscure thing; the main tag on the question is enough.

Comment: @PeterCordes The [top user in stdint has a score of 408](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdint/topusers). 40 makes it into the top 10. [cstdint is even worse](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cstdint/topusers)  I'm at 9 with a score of - wait for it - 14.  :-/   Only Lundin and R seem to have a high enough tag score so no way to get to 4 votes. (Just now saw your comment...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I edited the tags on this to include both (because stdint seems more relevant than integer), so now you have some tag-score in stdint, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunately, that didn't get me far enough.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: try again; it might have taken until overnight for tag scores to recalc.  It says you have 15, and creating synonyms only requires 5 in that tag (stdint).

Comment: @PeterCordes It worked this time:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdint/synonyms

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To determine if a fixed-width integer type is provided, you can check if either of the corresponding `[U]INT*_MAX` or `[U]INT*_MIN` macros is defined.

```
// may be necessary for your C++ implementation
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS 
#include <cstdint>

#ifdef INT32_MAX
// int32_t must be available to get here
int32_t some32bitIntVariable;
#endif
```

Per [**7.20 Integer types `<stdint.h>`**, paragraph 4 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20p4) (note the bolded parts):

> For each type described herein that the implementation provides, `<stdint.h>` shall declare that `typedef` name and **define the associated macros**. Conversely, for each type described herein that the implementation does not provide, `<stdint.h>` shall not declare that `typedef` name **nor shall it define the associated macros**.

C++ inherits the C implementation via `<cstdint>`.  See [**`<cstdint>` vs `<stdint.h>`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h) for some details.  Also see [**What do `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` and `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` mean?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986426/what-do-stdc-limit-macros-and-stdc-constant-macros-mean) for details on `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS`.

Thus, if `int32_t` is available, `INT32_MAX` and `INT32_MIN` must be `#define`'d. Conversely, if `int32_t` is not available, neither `INT32_MAX` nor `INT32_MIN` are allowed to be `#define`'d.

Note though, [as @NicolBolas stated in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59553383/4756299), it may not be necessary to actually check.

Comment: It'll be shorter to check for `[U]INT*_C` instead of the min & max macros

Comment: @phuclv Except that's not the same thing. e.g. `INT64_C` is defined if `int64_least_t` is available, not if `int64_t` is available. Refer to [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Answer (score 18):

Broadly speaking... you don't.

If you need to use the fixed-sized integer types, then that means that you explicitly *need* those types to be of their specific sizes. That is, your code will be non-functional if you cannot get integers of those sizes. So you should just use them; if someone uses your code on a compiler that lacks said types, then your code will not compile. Which is fine, because your code wouldn't have worked if it did compile.

If you don't actually *need* fixed-sized integers but simply want them for some other reason, then use the `int_least_*` types. If the implementation can give you exactly that size, then the `least_*` types will have that size.

Comment: This isn't true. I've written stub passthroughs that implement operator= / etc for platforms that don't support uint8_t before. But for efficiency and debugging purposes you don't want to use the passthrough unless its actually necessary.

Comment: @TLW: "*I've written stub passthroughs that implement operator= / etc for platforms that don't support uint8_t before.*" OK, but... why? What code were you writing which needs to be certain that a byte is 8 bits (which is presumably why you were using `uint8_t`), but this code somehow needed to run on a platform where a byte isn't 8 bits (which, besides using an old C++ implementation, would be the only reason why `uint8_t` wouldn't be available)? That is, outside of backwards compatibility, why did you need to do this?

Comment: proprietary so can't say too too much. Shared codebase that needed to support, among other things, a rather quirky hardware stack. `uint8_t` was _much_ clearer than the prior ad-hoc (and oft-broken) approach.

Comment: If you have an algorithm that is expressed in terms of e.g. 8-bit bytes, a passthrough is something that you can write once and is easy to test. Whereas fixing up every place is ad-hoc and easy to get subtly incorrect. `O(1)` versus `O(n)` effort. Same reason why people use e.g. `uint16_t`. You're asking "why not use uint32_t and cast it yourself?", to which the answer should be obvious.

Comment: @TLW: "*Same reason why people use e.g. uint16_t.*" That's not *my* reason for using `uint16_t`. My reason is that I'm communicating with a device/format/etc that is expecting to get precisely 16 bits of data formatted as a binary, unsigned integer using the endian for my machine, and if I can't get a type that is *precisely* that, then communicating effectively with it is much more difficult. My program (and the APIs that I use with it) fundamentally *cannot function* on a machine that doesn't provide that.

Comment: ping. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdint/synonyms needs votes to make cstdint a synonym; you're one of a few users with any tag score in it.