# Is it possible to determine at compile time whether an implementation provides exact-width integer types?

Tags: c, c11, stdint, c17

Is it possible to determine at compile time whether an implementation provides exact-width integer types? Sample code (wanted):

```
#include <stdint.h>

#if HAS_EXACT_WIDTH_INTEGER_TYPES
uint32_t    i;
#else
/* handle the case */
#endif
```

Reason of the question: writing an adaptable code, which does not lead to compile time errors if an implementation does not provide exact-width integer types.

Comment: So why not just `#ifdef UINT32_MAX`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552571/how-to-check-if-fixed-width-integers-are-defined

Comment: @KamilCuk Right, thanks! The same way is used to determine if an implementation supports `_Float16`: `#ifdef FLT16_MAX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C11/C17 7.20p4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20p4):

> 4. For each type described herein that the implementation provides, 261) `<stdint.h>` shall declare that typedef name and define the associated macros. **Conversely, for each type described herein that the implementation *does not provide***, `<stdint.h>` shall not declare that `typedef` name **nor shall it define the associated macros**. An implementation shall provide those types described as ''required'', but need not provide any of the others (described as ''optional'').

i.e. `uint32_t` exists **iff** `#defined UINT32_MAX`, etc.